# how to link panel accordion item to panel tabbed item

Tags: jsp, jsf, accordion, oracle-adf

I have created a tabbed panel and accordion panel. I would like to link each tab to each accordion so that when a tab is selected (or open) it's corresponding accordion would be selected and vice-versa. I am not too sure whether I am using the right components to get this effect. Please see the code and a screenshot below:

[image: image of adf page]

the code:

```
  <af:form id="f1">
            <af:panelSplitter orientation="vertical" splitterPosition="121" id="ps3">
                <f:facet name="first">
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="second">
                    <af:decorativeBox theme="dark" id="db3">
                        <f:facet name="center">
                            <af:decorativeBox theme="medium" id="db1">
                                <f:facet name="center">
                                    <af:panelSplitter orientation="horizontal" splitterPosition="201" id="ps1">
                                        <f:facet name="first">
                                         <af:panelAccordion discloseMany="true" id="pa1">
                                                        <af:showDetailItem id="pane1" text="A"/>
                                                        <af:showDetailItem id="pane2" text="B"/>
                                                        <af:showDetailItem id="pane3" text="C"/>
                                                    </af:panelAccordion>
                                        </f:facet>


                                        <f:facet name="second">
                                            <af:panelSplitter orientation="horizontal" splitterPosition="225"
                                                              positionedFromEnd="true" id="ps2">
                                                <f:facet name="first">
                                                    <af:decorativeBox theme="default" id="db2">
                                                        <f:facet name="center">
                                                            <af:panelSplitter id="ps4" orientation="vertical"
                                                                              splitterPosition="600">
                                                                <f:facet name="first">
                                                                    <af:panelTabbed position="above" id="pt2">
                                                                        <af:showDetailItem id="tab2"
                                                                                           text="A"
                                                                                           disclosed="true">
                                                                            <af:panelDashboard id="pd2"
                                                                                               inlineStyle="width:600px;"
                                                                                               dimensionsFrom="parent"/>
                                                                        </af:showDetailItem>
                                                                        <af:showDetailItem text="B"
                                                                                           id="sdi3"/>
                                                                        <af:showDetailItem text="C"
                                                                                           id="sdi4"/>
                                                                    </af:panelTabbed>
                                                                </f:facet>
                                                                <f:facet name="second">
                                                                    <af:panelTabbed position="above" id="pt1"/>
                                                                </f:facet>
                                                            </af:panelSplitter>
                                                        </f:facet>
                                                    </af:decorativeBox>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <f:facet name="second">

                                                </f:facet>
                                            </af:panelSplitter>
                                        </f:facet>
                                    </af:panelSplitter>
                                </f:facet>
                            </af:decorativeBox>
                        </f:facet>
                    </af:decorativeBox>
                </f:facet>
            </af:panelSplitter>
        </af:form>
```

Comment: I answered this a week ago, with code solution, but see no response or upvote if it helped, which it should have. If you don't give up votes I stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

TabbedPanel and Accordion both are containers for ShowDetailItem (SDI). ShowDetailItem has a DisclosureListener that indicates when it is "disclosed" - selected for viewing. Capture this listener in a backing bean. Then have the backing bean make the correct SDI/AccordionPanel the active panel by setting its disclosure property to true in the panelaccordion. You will have to "bind" the SDI(s) that you need into the Bean so that you can programatically set it's Disclosure property to true. Docs for SHowDetailItem [here](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_showDetailItem.html), panelaccordion [here](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_panelAccordion.html). You will also need to make the panel tab - the trigger of the event - a partial trigger source for the accordion so it gets refreshed.

Here's the bean code for example:

```
public class PanelTesterBean {
private RichShowDetailItem paSDI1;

public PanelTesterBean() {
}

public void tabSelected(DisclosureEvent disclosureEvent) {
   getPaSDI1().setDisclosed(true);
}

public void setPaSDI1(RichShowDetailItem paSDI1) {
    this.paSDI1 = paSDI1;
}

public RichShowDetailItem getPaSDI1() {
    return paSDI1;
}
```

}